# Inheritting Application in an android App

Tags: xamarin.android

I've got a small problem (and it's probably seriously nothing).

I have a small app which starts like this

```
namespace Paul.App
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/ApplicationName", MainLauncher = true, Theme =     "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar",
    ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Paul : Application
{

    public static Paul Application;

    public Paul(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(handle, transfer)
    {
```

In this app, I have

```
public Database dbm;
```

Database is a class which does SQL things

In this namespace, I also have an OnCreate which calls a new activity which starts like this

```
namespace Paul.App.Splash
{
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class Splash : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
```

This is fine and everything is ok. Except for one thing. I can't instantate the database!

If I put into the OnCreate or the the Paul(IntPtr...) and use in other activities

dbm = new DBManager();

the splash starts, but if I try and access dbm using ((Paul)Application).dbm it returns null.

If I do this in the Splash activity

```
((Paul)Application).dbm = new DBManager();
        if (((Paul)Application).dbm.SetupDB() != false)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Database failed to initialise", ToastLength.Long);
            return;
        }
```

the debugger tells me that ((Paul) is unknown.

It should be a simple thing to do - I'm trying to instantate SQLite once and then use it throughout the app.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In quickly looking through your code I see that you're decorating your Application class with the [Activity] attribute, which is incorrect. Instead what you want to do is use [`ApplicationAttribute`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.App.ApplicationAttribute), which will result in the proper AndroidManifest.xml output. Try changing it to look like this:

```
[Application(Label = "@string/ApplicationName", Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Paul : Application
{
    // ...
}
```